# Navigate from one stack to another

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I have a nested navigation structure. 

A Sign-In screen that needs to navigate to Profile screen and Profile needs to navigate to Inbox. Like so, Sign In -> Profile -> Inbox.

**Sing In**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Profile from "../Profile";

class AppSignIn extends React.Component{

_doSignIn(){
 this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')
}

render(){
  return(
     <View>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._doSignIn.bind(this)}>
          <Text>Go to Profile</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
     </View>
    )
 }
}

const AppSignInNav = createStackNavigator(
 {
    AppSignIn:{
    screen : AppSignIn
  },
  Profile:{
    screen:Profile
  }
 });

 export default createAppContainer(AppSignInNav);
```

**Profile**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Inbox from "../Inbox";

class Profile extends React.Component{

_goToInbox(){
 this.props.navigation.navigate('Inbox')
}

render(){
  return(
     <View>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._goToInbox.bind(this)}>
          <Text>Go to Inbox</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
     </View>
    )
 }
}

const ProfileNav = createStackNavigator(
 {
    Profile:{
    screen : Profile
  },
  Inbox:{
    screen : Inbox
  }
 });

 export default createAppContainer(ProfileNav);
```

How ever i get this error as a result of trying to navigate from **createStackNavigator** to another.
`The component for route 'Profile' must be a React component...` 
How can i export **Profile** as a React Component but still have it navigate to **Inbox**.?

Comment: try  `export default ProfileNav` instead of `export default createAppContainer(ProfileNav)`

Answer (score 0):

There can be only one `appContainer` for navigation. You are trying to create the app container twice using `createAppContainer`.

You can use `AppSignInNav` as the app container and export the `ProfileNav` as a normal `StackNavigator`.

Refer [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html) link for details on `createAppContainer` and its use.

Comment: Thank you Nair, I have realised what my issue was..The issue was more of a egg-chicken problem. I was importing **SignIn** inside **Profile** and also importing **Profile** inside **SignIn** which was a bad approach.